# How does Laravel dynamically call a class method statically without implicitly using the static keyword for the method in PHP?

Tags: php, static-methods, facade

Laravel makes it possible to call a class method using the scope resolution operator (::) without the method being statically declared.

In PHP you can only call static methods only when they are declared as such, for example:

```
class User {

   public static function getAge() { ... } 

}
```

Can be called as `User::getAge();`

How can this be done in a normal PHP class. I guess for it to be possible it needs to be done using a design pattern or something else. Can anyone help me out?

So what I meant by the above was is it possible to instantiate a class and call it's method statically in php. Since that feature was dropped from previous versions

```
class Student {

     public function examScore($mark_one, $mark_two) {
         //some code here
     }

}
```

How do access it in this manner

```
$student = new Student;
$student::examScore(20, 40);
```

And I talked about Laravel because it allows you to alias your classes and call it in this manner `Student::examScore(20,40);`

Something called facade pattern or so. An explanation with example can help.

After a long search I found an article that kind of explains it here:

```
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of such a method in Laravel and how you would call it to make it clear what you are referring to?

Comment: An example is how the Blade class is used to call its methods example Blade::compileString($param)

Comment: This first two videos [here](https://laravelcoreadventures.com/the-chamber-of-facades/level/1) would also be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks Delena the videos really helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess here is that your User class actually extends the Laravel `Model` class.

This class implements some of PHPs so called magic methods. You can find our about them here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

One of these is `__callStatic`.

In `Model.php`:

```
/**
 * Handle dynamic static method calls into the method.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array  $parameters
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    return (new static)->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

Comment: No I am not using Laravel Model. I want to know how it can be done in raw PHP. Can you help with a little real world example please

Comment: @ A.L. this answer has been very helpful but I what I was looking for is explained here : https://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere/ thanks so much